# cannot run smack android client on android studio

Tags: android, smack

I imported smack project to android studio from [here](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack)

, But it gives me this error:

```
Error:(453, 0) ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set
="openFile:C:\Users\Downloads\Compressed\Smack-master\Smack-master\build.gradle">Open File
```

I didn't change anything in **Build.gradle** file I just configured sdk version and build tool like:

```
android {
      compileSdkVersion 24
      buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
}
```

Comment: hi. You can try add new if not exits a file: local.properties in root of project (same level with build.gradle) after ward you add string refer to sdk on window as: sdk.dir = your_sdk_path

Comment: solution is here **ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set**